# What tools are best to investigate USB devices on Windows

Tags: python, usb

I have been developing some code in python/pyUSB on LINUX for a USB device primarily used on Windows. I have tried SNOOPY which does not work on Win7 to examine the messages. I have used BUSDOG which works but I want more detail. I have also used lsusb on LINUX to examine the device but I still can't see everything. What are other people using?

I have read a good article on [hacking the Kinect by Ladyada](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/diykinect/)

Also general details on USB devices and how they work [USB made simple](http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_4.htm) but I am missing some details

I want to discover more detail on the structure of control_transfer messages that I generate in Windows so that I can replicate that in Python on LINUX

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I've been using BusHound (http://www.perisoft.net). It has to advantage of being software-only, and not as expensive as a hardware solutions. This is a Windows-only solution. There is a free version, but I don't know what the limitations are.

Another option is to use hardware capture tools, but they are rather expensive.

Comment: Thanks I had a look at bushound - it is hard to tell as free version is pretty restrictive - full version is $800. Then I found AGG Software's Advanced USB Port Monitor Free version pretty good - Paid 60EUR. Probably not as complete as BusHound - it mostly does the job. I will keep looking though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did not realise BusHound was so expensive (I was using an existing site licence). Will look at AGG's solution next time I need such a tool.